# Redux Testing unexpected Token error

Tags: testing, redux, mocha.js, babeljs, babel-core

I am running into an issue with a test_helper file that use to work perfectly fine. It is a project I am coming back to after a while. The error and file are below along with the package.json as I suspect it maybe the compiler causing the issue.

The Error

```
SyntaxError: /Users/mikewalters/Projects/video-
frontend/test/test_helper.js: Unexpected token (20:4)
18 | function renderComponent(ComponentClass, props = {}, state = {}) {
19 |   const componentInstance =  TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
> 20 |     <Provider store={createStore(reducers, state)}>
   |     ^
21 |       <ComponentClass {...props} />
22 |     </Provider>
23 |   );
```

The test_helperjs

```
import _$ from 'jquery';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiJquery from 'chai-jquery';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../src/reducers';

global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = global.document.defaultView;
const $ = _$(window);

chaiJquery(chai, chai.util, $);

function renderComponent(ComponentClass, props = {}, state = {}) {
  const componentInstance =  TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers, state)}>
      <ComponentClass {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );

  return $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(componentInstance));
}

$.fn.simulate = function(eventName, value) {
  if (value) {
    this.val(value);
  }
  TestUtils.Simulate[eventName](this[0]);
};

export {renderComponent, expect};
import _$ from 'jquery';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiJquery from 'chai-jquery';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../src/reducers';

global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = global.document.defaultView;
const $ = _$(window);

chaiJquery(chai, chai.util, $);

function renderComponent(ComponentClass, props = {}, state = {}) {
  const componentInstance =  TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers, state)}>
      <ComponentClass {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );

  return $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(componentInstance));
}

$.fn.simulate = function(eventName, value) {
  if (value) {
    this.val(value);
  }
  TestUtils.Simulate[eventName](this[0]);
};

export {renderComponent, expect};
```

The package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha -r mock-local-storage --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "coverage": "babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/isparta cover --include 'src/**/*.js*' _mocha"
  },
```

These test have worked before and the fact that it isnt even getting to the test lends me to believe it is something with the compiler or package that changed. But I haven't been able to find anything online about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a .babelrc file. Ended up adding this and it started to work

```
{
 "presets": [ "react","es2015","es2016","stage-0" ]
}
```